# Trigger.io load page dynamically

Tags: trigger.io

So I was using trigger.io to create a page where there's a custom menu at the bottom and each button loads an external HTML page into main container. I had to hack around to make this work so I was wondering if there's a better way of doing it.

I started using the `$('.main').load('pages/test.html')` and it doesn't work. Instead I had to do:

```
forge.file.getLocal('pages/test.html', function (file) {
  forge.file.string(file, function (str) {
    $('.main').html(str);
  });
});
```

which is kinda messy.

Also if the `str` HTML content as a `img` tag, the img doesn't show since the `src` attribute gets messed up. So I had to do another hack:

```
forge.file.getLocal('pages/test.html', function (file) {
  forge.file.string(file, function (str) {
    var $main = $('.main');
    $main.html(str);

    //Hack to resolve img src
    var imgPath;
    $main.find('img').each(function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      // First 8 chars is "file:///"
      imgPath = $this.prop('src').substr(8);
      forge.file.getLocal(imgPath, function (file) {
        $this.prop('src', file.uri);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Any better way of purely loading an external HTML page without all the hassle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Testing with forge platform v1.4 (at the time of writing, v1.4.18) on Android 4.1 and iOS (both the iPhone simulator and an iPad), I seem to be able to use jQuery's load method without any extra effort. Here's the structure for my testcase:

```
src/
  index.html
  face.png
  pages/
    hello.html
```

Here's the contents of `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.content').load('pages/hello.html');
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="content">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And `pages/hello.html`:

```
<b>hello world</b><img src="face.png">
```

Which resulted in this just after app launch:
[image: Result of using $.fn.load]

One gotcha I can see with this approach is that the `src` attribute for the `img` tag had to be relative to `index.html`. If you're still having problems then a more specific testcase and/or details of forge platform version used as well as what devices/simulators you tested on might be useful.

Comment: The example did work. But when I put it in a script, it doesn't. Let me elaborate my flow a bit:

I use Backbone.Router to route `<a>` tag and in each route I do a `$('.content').load` and that didn't work.

The other weird thing is, after a night, I did a `forge build ios; forge run ios` and `window.location` no longer works, the error is that it cannot find `file:///login.html` when I redirects `window.location = login.html`. It was working the night before.

Somehow this is too unstable.

Comment: @LongHo It's not clear what you mean by "when I put it in a script". For example, I can modify my example above so that the JavaScript is in a separate js file, and still get the result displayed above. Could you edit your original question to include steps to reproduce your problem, including code? WRT your problem with `window.location`, it would probably be best to create a separate question about it, including steps to reproduce.

Comment: I meant when I put the loading piece into a separate script and import it inside `<head>`. Now I started to think it's the simulator's fault.